# How to authenticate and list users / run different graph ql api's using Microsoft graph API

Tags: go, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-application-registration

I've created an enterprise application /application registration in azure cloud console . And created web credentials client secret.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal

I am using microsoft go sdks to authenticate with client secrets and get the list of users / list of apps / graph client current user that are part of the enterprise application which I created earlier.  Please find the below code.  However following code is returning error every time on go sdk calls.

```
package main

import (
    "context" 
    "fmt" 
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
    "github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/to" 
    msgraphsdk "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go"
    msgraphcore "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go-core" 
    a "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go-core/authentication" 
    "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/applications" 
    "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/models" 
    "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/users" 
    "log" 
)

func main() {

    cred, err := azidentity.NewClientSecretCredential("dd....", "10...", "LV....", nil)
    
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    auth, err := a.NewAzureIdentityAuthenticationProviderWithScopes(cred, []string{"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    requestAdapter, err := msgraphsdk.NewGraphRequestAdapter(auth)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    graphClient := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(requestAdapter)
    query := users.UserItemRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters{
        Select: []string{"displayName", "jobTitle"},
    }
    
    options := users.UserItemRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration{
        QueryParameters: &query,
    }
    
    result, err := graphClient.Me().Get(context.Background(), &options)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error getting users: %v\n", err)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    appGetOptions := &applications.ApplicationsRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration{
        QueryParameters: &applications.ApplicationsRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters{
            Filter: to.StringPtr(getDisplayNameFilter("swagger")),
        },
    }
    
    _, err_ := graphClient.Applications().Get(context.Background(), appGetOptions)
    if err_ != nil {
        log.Fatal(err_)
    }

}

func getDisplayNameFilter(displayName string) string {
 return fmt.Sprintf("displayName eq '%s'", displayName) 
}
```

When I run the above code the following error is encountered with response code as 0.

*Error getting users: error status code received from the API*

Can you please let me know what am I doing wrong that's causing the errors while running the program?

Answer (score 0):

When using client secret you cannot get details for the current user because you are not logged as any user. Calling `graphClient.Me()` will never work. You can get only info for all users.

```
import (
      "context"
      msgraphsdk "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go"
      graphusers "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/users"
      //other-imports
)

cred, err := azidentity.NewClientSecretCredential("dd....", "10...", "LV....", nil)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

auth, err := a.NewAzureIdentityAuthenticationProviderWithScopes(cred, []string{"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
requestAdapter, err := msgraphsdk.NewGraphRequestAdapter(auth)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

graphClient := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(requestAdapter)

requestParameters := &graphusers.UsersRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters{
    Select: [] string {"displayName","jobTitle"},
}
configuration := &graphusers.UsersRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration{
    QueryParameters: requestParameters,
}

users, err := graphClient.Users().Get(context.Background(), configuration)
```